# What does the phrase "plug skill points into complementary techniques" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrases

What does the phrase "plug skill points into complementary techniques" mean in the following text from a wrestling game:

> For new fighters, you should **plug skill points into complementary
> techniques.** For example, Mix agility with takedowns to become a fast
> wrestler, or improve elbows and clinchwork for an aggressive Thai
> boxing style.

For some context, this is a tip given to players.

Answer (score 1):

In this sense, the closest meaning of “plug X into” is to insert a number into an equation, or data into a form. It’s understandable to a native English speaker who games, but that isn’t the clearest way to express it in my opinion. I probably would have said “put skill points into complementary techniques”.

Collins dictionary has [a definition of the phrasal verb “plug in”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plug-in):

> If you plug something into a hole, you push it into the hole.
> *Her instructor plugged live bullets into the gun's chamber.*

This applies to figurative holes as well, like blanks in a form or variables in an equation. For example, you could “plug the numbers from step one into the equation”.